# How can I capture a one-time full backup of a server using AMANDA?

Tags: backup, amanda

Suppose I have a preconfigured AMANDA server running automated network backups of directories specified in my `disklists` file. Normally, AMANDA will backup targets disks to `/dumps/amanda`.

**Is there any single command or method to perform a manual, one-time, full backup dump to another destination drive?**

I ask since I'm investigating the possibility of introducing rotating external hard-drive backups for offsite storage and I want to leverage our existing backup strategies wherever possible. Ideally, a full backup restore should be achievable from only any one of these offsite backup discs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  From the **amadmin** man page:

```
force [ hostname [ disks ]* ]+
           Force the disks on hostname to do a full (level 0) backup during the next Amanda run.
```

So, to make Amanda do a full dump of one specific host, use:

```
 amadmin DailySet1 force myonehost
```

To make Amanda do a full dump of everything, use;

```
  amadmin DailySet1 force
```

To then tell Amanda to run the backup now, just do:

```
amdump DailySet1 myonehost
```

You may also want to look at the man pages for the **amvault** command.